# How to build c# UWP-based project to one .exe file?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, native

I want to use universal windows in my project for windows 10 only. I need to compile all my UI&logic stuff to one exe-file (or dll). Like I could do the same with usual WPF application.
But results of build contains a lot of .xbf files and .net-libraries. I already tryed to set "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" options in project's build settings, but the results still contains a lot of files.

Answer (score 1):

Within the [uwp](/questions/tagged/uwp) development framework, there's no such thing as an `exe` file.

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/whats-a-uwp):

> Apps are packaged and distributed using the .AppX packaging format.
>
> All UWP apps are distributed as an AppX package. This provides a
>   trustworthy installation mechanism and ensures that your apps can be
>   deployed and updated seamlessly.

This is the same scenario as it was with Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 applications using the `WinRT` framework.

If you need an `exe` file just to install your app without going through the store, take a look at the **sideloading option for UWP**.

You can find more info about creating packages, going through the store and sideloading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps).

Comment: Thx for answer but i can't find opportunity to local copy/installation. WinAppDeploy util requires an external device for deploying