# Compile .net app to single exe

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-native

I’m wondering is there any way using tooling of todays .NET for compiling app to single exe? Couple years ago when I read about .Net Native it was promising for compilation that gives all necessary code in app without .net framework and using some tree shaking mechanism compile to single file with only the code that is actually used by application. Is this actually doable now? I now that WPF and Winforms are coming in .NET core 3.0 but is this possible to create such application in UWP?

Comment: Similar/Same question: [How to build c# UWP-based project to one .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718489/how-to-build-c-sharp-uwp-based-project-to-one-exe-file)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, this has been supported in UWP for a while. In VS, check this box to compile everything into one big binary:

[image]

Comment: I tried this yesterday with clean UWP project – I clean bin and build with this option but I don’t see any big file. My TestApp.exe have 19KB and there are lot of dll’s in bin (I’m using VS 2017 15.7.1). What I’m missing?

Comment: Take a look into the .\appx\ subfolder. That is the actual, final output that gets deployed. In there you should see a tiny TestApp.exe  as entrypoint and a single TestApp.dll that contains everything.

Comment: Ok I can see now - this folder was created after run app in VS/deploy, atfer build it is not there. But should I be able to run this app from exe? I tired and I have error "the code execution cannot proced becouse SharedLibrary.dll was not found" and next the same for mrt100_app.dll?

Comment: No, you can't just launch a UWP EXE, you have to launch via a proper launch contract. By default you can launch from the start menu, but you can also declare other activation kinds in the manifest (file, protocol, etc.). If you want to launch from the commandline, then declare an appExecutionAlias. If you want to launch programmatically, look at IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication.